# why ordered list clicked id changing automatically when using if condition

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi i am using one ordered list to show accordion using jquery so here i am checking which list is clicked by user but when i am using if condition it is changing automatically.
Below is the code for that.

```html
 <ol class="rounded light" id="accordion_1" style="width:auto; height: auto; padding-right:2px">
            <li id="Head">              
                <div id="CasHeadCount" data-bkgrnd-img="../Content/images/groupemployee.png">Head Count</div>
                <div>
                    <figure>
                        <figcaption id="Chartcaption">
                            <a onclick="BindDefault()" id="HomeChart" style="cursor:pointer;"></a>
                            <a id="DrillDownChart"></a>
                        </figcaption>
                        @*<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/1.jpg")" alt="image" />*@
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                Head Content
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </figure>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="Attrition">
                <div id="CasAttrition" data-bkgrnd-img="../Content/images/AttritionChart.png">Attrition Metrics</div>
                <div>
                    <figure>
                         <div>
                            <div>
                                Attrition Content
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </figure>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ol>
```

and below is the jquery code where i am getting the id of list which is clicked by user

```html
 $("#accordion_1 li").not('.emptyMessage').click(function () {
                debugger;
                var ActiveListid = this.id;
                var Hiddid = $("#hdnval");
                Hiddid.val(ActiveListid);
                var Activeid = Hiddid.val();
                var gridhead = $("#GridHeadCount");
                var gAttritionMet = $("#GridAttrition");

                if (Activeid = "Head")
                {
                    gridhead.show();

                    gAttritionMet.hide();
                }
                else if (Activeid = "Attrition")
                {
                    gridhead.hide();

                    gAttritionMet.show();
                }
            });
```

So when i am checking in first variable getting the same id which is clicked but when use if condition id is changing automatically.
to avoid this i also used hidden field here but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the assignment operator `=` instead of equality operators `==` or `===`

change

```
if (Activeid = "Head") {
    gridhead.show();

    gAttritionMet.hide();
} else if (Activeid = "Attrition") {
    gridhead.hide();

    gAttritionMet.show();
}
```

to

```
if (Activeid == "Head") {
    gridhead.show();

    gAttritionMet.hide();
} else if (Activeid == "Attrition") {
    gridhead.hide();

    gAttritionMet.show();
}
```

Comment: Oh god thanks DGS u have saved my time. i was doing a very small silly mistake. i am marking it as answer.